# How to use LIKE operator in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and I'm trying to filter part of the text of a string. For example, I want to get when in a text there is 'Credit Note' what happens is that there are values like "Generate Credit Note Manually".

In SQL Server I know it works using:

```
Select Column1
From Table1
Where Column1 LIKE '% Credit% Note%'
```

But I don't get the above in Oracle, does not return any match with "Generate Credit Note Manually".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably, there are other characters that may be hidden that are causing a problem.

Comment: @TheImpaler It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e627/1

Comment: In Oracle string comparison is case **sensitive** so `'%Credit%Note'` will not match the value `'Generate credit note'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're using is correct.

If the query isn't returning the data there might be something wrong with the data. I know it might look like plain text but sometimes there are invisible encoding along with it, especially if it was copy-pasted from a heavy word processor like MS Word or something.

Create additional rows and write the text manually to make sure there are no encoding being copied. Also, try copy-pasting the value from the table into notepad, see it pastes some additional symbols. Also, check to see if it's a case-sensitivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1
From Table1
Where Column1 LIKE '%Credit Note%'
```

You don't have to add `%` to represent the white space. The `like` operator can take in string and white spaces when you wrap them up in this way `'text to search'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Select Column1 
From Table1 
Where Column1 LIKE '%Credit%'  
  or Column1 LIKE '%Note%'
```

If you need matching these words together try to use REGEXP_LIKE()